# Pretty URLs rewrite sometimes with "?" sometimes without

Tags: apache, wordpress, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I hope someone can answer "why" this is the case:

There are times I can use:

```
...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and then there are times where the above doesn't work and I must use:

```
...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

the main difference being the addition of `?` ... I typically see this happen on different system setups, fastcgi vs module vs cgi, but haven't done enough setups to see the pattern.

I am guessing that it is related to how the apache/setup parses path/path_info data. Any thoughts are welcomed, ideally I'd like to have a solid explanation of why this is and when it occurs.

On the same thread ... Sometimes Apache does not output `PATH_INFO` environment var which might be the root cause of this, but I wonder why that is.

Comment: Probably governed by the `AcceptPathInfo` apache config option.

Comment: I played with `AcceptPathInfo` but it didn't seem to effect anything, at least it appeared that way.

Comment: you are talking about wordpress or codeigniter or both? Because, they both implement their own routing rules.

Comment: codeigniter primarily, I am not sure if I've encountered this with WordPress (I think WP does its routing better than CI, they keep it simple and rely on PHP more)

Comment: Have you tried `qsappend|QSA`?

Comment: I ran into the same issue. My Wintel 7 Apache 2.2 works fine without the trailing question mark. However, on my Linux host the trailing question mark is required, otherwise all requests are dispatched to the default controller in routes.php.

Comment: the only thing i can currently attribute this to is the differences in running SAPI, CGI or FastCGI

Comment: I'm pretty sure the lack of `PATH_INFO` environment var is related, as that's how pretty URLs are implemented in Wordpress.  Have you looked at the `cgi.fix_pathinfo` setting for [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)?  There's no good documentation about it, but this definitely looks like a reasonable lead...

Answer (score 0):

The ? is the marker of the beginning of the query string.

So basically your first rule rewrite a URL `"x"` to a file `"x"` in the directory `index.php`, the second rewrite a URL `"x"` to the `index.php` file with parameter `"x"`. [(BTW I don't know how to retrieve a variable with no name in the file, usually you use `?var=value&var2=value2` etc...)